# Angular 6 navbar routerlink reload component

Tags: php, angular, routes, navigation, angular6

Im using angular 6 and a routerlink in a dropdown menu in my navbar. The problem i'm facing is that routerlink isn't reloading the website and therefor not the route. When pressing a button in the dropdown it initially loads correctly, but when the user presses another button in the dropdown (while still on another child-page of the dropdown) it doesnt reload the content on the page, but changes the URL. When using Href it loads everything correctly.

```
<div 
  ngbDropdownMenu 
  class="dropdown-menu" 
  aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
  <div *ngFor="let competentie of competenties">
    <a 
      class="dropdown-item" 
      routerlink="/competenties/{{competentie.id}}">
      {{competentie.name}}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This forces me to use href instead of routerlink to reload the page for the component to reload and display the content with the right {{competentie.id}}.

Is there a way to navigate to another dropdown-page with routerlink and update the content on the page?

### Edit

The details component:

```
export class CompetentieComponent implements OnInit {
competentie: Competentie;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private competentieService: CompetentieService,
            private location: Location
) {
}

getCompetentie(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.competentieService.getCompetentie(id)
        .subscribe(competentie => this.competentie = competentie);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getCompetentie();
}
}
```

My route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'competenties/:id', component: CompetentieComponent}
];
```

The service, gets it data from a class with array COMPETENTIES[]:

```
export class CompetentieService {

getCompetenties(): Observable<Competentie[]> {
    return of(COMPETENTIES);
}

getCompetentie(id: number): Observable<Competentie> {
    return of(COMPETENTIES.find(competentie => competentie.id === id));
}

constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Use RouterLink like that : `[routerLink]="['/competenties/'+ competentie.id]"` instead of `routerlink="/competenties/{{competentie.id}}"`

Comment: @ShashikantDevani, isn't the latter the same as the former?

Comment: Yes it is, just an old way of using the routerlink. Still get the same problem.

Comment: It's not an old way or a new way. It's just two different ways of doing the same thing. It's just a matter of using the one that makes more sense as compared to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')` which will only trigger just once. You should be using `params` instead of `snapshot.paramMap.get('id')`. `params` is a `BehaviorSubject` subscribing to which will give you the updated `id` every time it changes.

You should inject `ActivatedRoute` as a dependency in the same and then subscribe to `params` property on it.

```
export class CompetentieComponent implements OnInit {
  competentie: Competentie;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private competentieService: CompetentieService,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  getCompetentie(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      let latestID = +params['id'];
      this.competentieService.getCompetentie(latestID)
        .subscribe(competentie => this.competentie = competentie);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCompetentie();
  }

}
```

Comment: That was a typo but not really the problem im facing. Routerlink is working fine but it's not refreshing the component and therfore not updatting the content.

Comment: Hover over the Option and check where it is navigating the user. Also if possible, please consider creating a stackblitz.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with navigation, everything is working fine. The only problem I have is the component not reloading when im in the same component. So im in /details/3 and when switching to /details/4 with routerLink the component doesn't reload (because the same component is showing) so content like title and description isn't changing. When using href instead of routerlink the component reloads and shows the content belonging to the right id.

Comment: You should post your route config and Component code as well in that case. It's difficult to figure that out without that code. Better create a StackBlitz if possible. Also have a look at the updated Answer once and check if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Updated my post with the router, component and service. Hope this can help you understand what i'm trying to do. I understand I have to check if there were any events in the url/routes that change. But I dont know how to check this and reload the component to find the content for the new ID.

Comment: You should be using `params`. I've updated my answer accordingly. Please check.

Comment: This worked! I understand where I went wrong with the snapshots. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wow, I spent a few hours with the same problem and finally stumbled across this - works perfectly!!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following for dynamic routes:

```
<a class="dropdown-item"  [routerLink]="['/competenties/' + competentie.id]">
  {{competentie.name}}
</a>
```

Comment: Nope, same problem. Because it loads the same component, it doesnt execute the OnInit. Only fix for now is using href but doesnt look clean.

Answer (score -1):

add this to your code:

```
<a class="dropdown-item"  [routerLink]="['/competenties/' + competentie.id]">
  {{competentie.name}}
</a>
```